# Woocommerce + Gravity Forms

Tags: woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity Forms with Woocommerce. For some calculations we need to use hidden fields. With `display: none;` in the CSS file, 
they don't show up on the front. So far so good.

But when you order a product and receive the order mail from Woocommerce, you see all the hidden fields...

How do I exclude certain fields, so it will not be enclosed by Woocommerce.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

http://gravitywiz.com/how-to-hide-gravity-forms-product-fields/

Long story short, you can't use display none to hide Product fields if you want them to count towards the Total. Use { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; } instead.

Comment: Thanx for your reply, i know i cant use display:none; i mean  visibility: hidden; But the problem is that, the site is working fine. But de hidden fields show up in the mails... From Woocommerce. The also need to be hidden in the mails.